# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The directory property cannot be found in the cache

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When we're trying to check if the local user account's password is expired, by retrieving the value of the property **PasswordExpirationDate**. It’s failing in some environments with an exception - **The directory property cannot be found in the cache”.**

```
“An exception has occured and the exception is:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The directory property cannot be found in the cache”.
```

When running the below code,

```html
using (var userEntry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + domain + '/' + user + ",user"))
                                    {
DateTime expiryDate = (DateTime)userEntry.InvokeGet("PasswordExpirationDate");
```

Comment: Looks like the wrong property name, it see other code using the much more intuitive "pwdLastSet" ;)  The scripting code [on this page](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-get-a-user-password-c1c8fd18) might be helpful to see the corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the *userEntry* object got from *DirectoryEntry*, for the *PasswordExpirationDate*?